# Jquery Doesnt Detect Multiple OnChange Value Before Clone to Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i having problem on this issue

my jquery code doesnt take effect on the if else statement and even i dint did any changes , it still clone the date to the dialog.

Here my code :

```
$("#opendialog").click(function() {

  alert($("input#newsDate").val());
  if(newsDate != $("input#newsDate").val()){

    var clonetext = $('#newsDate').clone(true);    
    $('#previewDiv').html(clonetext);

    $( "#previewDiv" ).dialog( "open" );
    alert(newsdateChangesomething);
    return false;

  } else if (newsDate == $("input#newsDate").val()) {
    var clonetext = $('newsTitle').clone(false);

    alert(333)
    return false;
  } else if (newsTitle != $("input#newsTitle").val()){
    var clonetext = $('#newsTitle').clone(true);    
    $('#previewDiv').html(clonetext);

    $( "#previewDiv" ).dialog( "open" );
    alert(TITLE333);
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Where is the value of `newsDate` set?

Comment: my newsDate value = "dd-MMM-yyyy"

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newsDate, new { id = "newsDate" })